# Saving HTML report by showing Save As dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, save

I want to show a Save As dialog box to user in my MVC application and allow him to save some HTML report in the format of pdf or word. For doing this, do I need to play with File stream and IO functions at server side? Or is it possible at JQuery level itself?

I found some references on web like adding a response header Content-Disposition, but not getting how to apply it. Can you please suggest some options?

Answer (score 0):

You must create a descendant from `ActionResult` that plays with output the desired way.

This is a class of mine I created to implement a "Save as Excel" feature:

```
            public class ExcelResult : ActionResult
            {
                private string _fileName;
                private IQueryable _rows;
                private string[] _headers = null;
                private string _data;

                private TableStyle _tableStyle;
                private TableItemStyle _headerStyle;
                private TableItemStyle _itemStyle;

                public string FileName
                {
                    get { return _fileName; }
                }

                public IQueryable Rows
                {
                    get { return _rows; }
                }



                public ExcelResult(string data, string fileName)
                {
                    _fileName = fileName;
                    _data = data;
                }

                public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
                {
                    WriteFile(_fileName, "application/ms-excel", _data);            
                }


                private string ReplaceSpecialCharacters(string value)
                {
                    value = value.Replace("’", "'");
                    value = value.Replace("“", "\"");
                    value = value.Replace("”", "\"");
                    value = value.Replace("–", "-");
                    value = value.Replace("…", "...");
                    return value;
                }

                private void WriteFile(string fileName, string contentType, string content)
                {
                    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
                    context.Response.Clear();
                    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
                    context.Response.Charset = "";
                    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
                    context.Response.Write(content);
                    context.Response.End();
                }
            }
```

You can use this example to generate HTML for word. PDF are a different matter, tho'.